# engineer dilemma: when my line manager is not the product manager

Tags: company-culture, politics

I'm kind of the only software guy in the team which has been working quite independently. Only my boss's boss has some good understanding of what I'm doing and he is the only one in the team I feel sharing the same page, despite he is not as technical as me, but at least he tries to be. Thus, we work quite closely.

Lately, this big boss got the promotion and thus becomes less available for  projects on my side. He begins to empower a newly arrive product manager who knows nothing about technology but finance and business. (I work in a financial institution by the way). The PM is not even my manager and we are just colleagues.

My boss makes me work with her (the PM). However, she begins to act as if it's my manager (asking about my progress, pushing me to have useless meetings despites I'm busy working on the requirements and I need some extra time before I'm fully prepared to present). I understand it's part of the job of PM to hold useless meetings to show they are actually doing work, and PM is supposed to be empowered with monitoring the project progress. However, she is not even my manager and has nothing to do with my appraisal. I'm thinking as long as I satisfy the requests directly from my big boss, I just don't need to give a hook of this stupid PM who knows nothing about technology.

Even worse, the PM always steal my ideas and presents as hers with long emails. Gradually I lose trust in her and avoid sharing my ideas with her in private. She kept doing this and eventually I rebutted her with another long email, hinting she always packages my idea and presents as her own. However, my big boss was quite unhappy about my email (I'm very polite and asked for open discussion among all stakeholders), saying he is busy and tell us guys to discuss among ourselves instead of involving him all the time.

I feel hurt, as I'm the victim, and apparently my big boss is blaming the victim. However, my ranks are lower than theirs, I also feel quite helpless in terms of what I could do. If I cooperate with her, she keeps on stealing my ideas. If I don't, my big boss would think I'm not doing my work. More importantly, all those stupid meetings and administratives are just eating my time for my serious work. Helping others to do their job at my own expense is the thing that I want least to see. 'Raising' a PM kid is not part of my job description.

What should I do? 
How can I work with a PM who is not my line manager to my benefit? This is a strange reporting structure in a way I'm not directly reporting to PM per se. How could I draw a line between helping the PM do their job and helping myself doing the job? Again, I've zero interests in helping others to do their job if there's no good for me.

Comment: "What should I do" is a question which tends to draw opinions rather than factual answers. Try to focus in on a specific "should I" or "how can I."  Also note that questions which require a lot of situational background tend to be regarded as a poster seeking validation rather than a solution. I'm not the downvoter, but those are the things I think most likely to have caused that reaction. Consider editing to focus more precisely on an actionable problem.

Comment: There's also a VTC reason stating "*Questions require a goal that we can address. Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better.*". So not only you need to set a clear goal but also dodge the "*opinion-based*" bullet(list of options)

Comment: i guess it should be specific enough after editing. Thanks the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You come across as very judgemental. Paired with the fact that you don't seem to understand what the PMs job actually *is* is a sure way to get you on your bosses bad side and fired sooner or later.

You probably have some valid points, but half of your post is complaining that the PM is doing the job they should be doing. That will get you nowhere. What would your boss even do, hire a PM that does their job worse than the current one?

So what can you do?

1. Accept that you now have a project manager and that managing a project is their job and they will be doing it. Does it distract from programming? Oh yes. Is it neccessary for any organisation, to grow? Oh yes. You can call it project manager/business analyst or a product owner/scrum master, but most if not all ways of organizing programmers to build something bigger than a two person garage project needs multiple persons to feed requirements to the software engineers and funnel back the results so that everybody gets a say and stays informed. If you are unclear how that works, ask your boss to clarify the roles and what part of your former job duties went to the PM.
2. Accept that other roles in your company can do their job and do it well even without a programming background. In fact, you *want* them to have a different background, otherwise they would not be good at *their* job. A PM cannot tell you what pattern to use, what compiler setting or language feature, but they can absolutely tell you which of the tasks has priority over the other. A CS background is not needed to manage a project.
3. Talk to the PM and tell them that if you had an idea for the project you shared with them, you want to get credit in the mails she sends. If she does not understand that, then you can either send those mails yourself copying them in, or stop giving them ideas. You work for the company, not for the PM.
4. Read a book or two about project management. It helps to understand the other roles you work with, what they need from you and what they are supposed to deliver to you.
5. Give your boss feedback through the proper channels. Tell them how much time you spent away from your computer each week due to those new meetings. If in the end, having a PM slows down the progress of the project, they need to know. *However* be aware that the PM *is* saving time for someone somewhere. So just saying "I spent time in meetings, that sucks" is not going to help your case. Tell your boss how much slower the project goes (if it does). Only your boss can figure out, if that is worth it. I find it strange to have a 1:1 ratio of PM to Programmer, so maybe your boss plans to hire more programmers and lift your product from single coder to actual software team.

That said... try this in good faith and maybe you will get a good result. I have had mixed results with this, because sometimes you *are* expected to "raise a PM" next to your work. Because for some reason a software developer is only good if they have studied for years and then had years of experience on top, but for PMs, sometimes bosses just pick the next best friendly face, with no credits to their name and no experience. I have worked multiple jobs where I had literally more PM experience than the PM, just because I had managed projects in the past when the PM was on sick leave or something. I would suggest you try your best with the points above, but sometimes you need to add

6. if the PM does not understand their job, and the boss does not understand the PM job enough to replace the PM with someone that does, it's time to value your own sanity and find a better company. I love teaching people, but those people need to *know* they are bad at their jobs and *willing* to improve. With half the PMs I have met in my 25 years journey, that was not the case.

Comment: thanks @nvoigt, I'm thankful you try to honestly point out my issues despite I'm not explicit in my questions. I think your advice helps.